# PHP keep me from eval ;) Variables inside string

Tags: php, eval

For reasons I'd rather not get into right now, I have a string like so:

```
<div>$title</div>
```

that gets stored in a database using `mysql_real_escape_string`.

During normal script execution, that string gets parsed and stored in a variable `$string` and then gets sent to a `function($string)`.

In this function, I am trying to:

```
function test($string){
  $title = 'please print';
  echo $string;
}
//I want the outcome to be <div>please print</div>
```

This seems like the silliest thing, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to "interpret" the variables.

I've also tried,

```
echo html_entity_decode($string);
echo bin2hex(html_entity_decode($string)); //Just to see what php was actually seeing I thought maybe the $ had a slash on it or something.
```

I decided to post on here when my mind kept drifting to using `EVAL()`.

This is just pseudocode, of course. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to get that to work. You are trying something like this:

```
$var = "cute text";
echo 'this is $var';
```

The single quotes are preventing the interpreter from looking for variables in the string. And it is the same, when you echo a string variable.

The solution will be a simple `str_replace`.

```
echo str_replace('$title', $title, $string);
```

But in this case I really suggest Template variables that are unique in your text.

Comment: Smarty uses curly braces around a PHP style var, {$like} {$these}.

Comment: Just to note if you change your single apostrophe to a double apostrophe your first example will work, this also goes for setting the string variable, so its not necessarily when you echo a string variable. If you set `$string = 'this is $var';` you will get exactly that on echo, but use `$string = "this is $var";` you will get `this is cute text` when echoing `$string`.

Comment: @Scoobler You are right. The snippet I posted was just intended to demonstrate what happens in the questions example.

Comment: You're welcome! Please note that @markus's answer is more common for single replacements. My method is mainly used for templates where several variables exist in one template string.

Answer (score 3):

Your example is a bit abstract. But it seems like you could do pretty much what the template engines do for these case:

```
function test($string){
   $title = 'please print';

   $vars = get_defined_vars();
   $string = preg_replace('/[$](\w{3,20})/e', '$vars["$1"]', $string);

   echo $string;
}
```

Now actually, `/e` is pretty much the same as using eval. But at least this only replaces actual variable names. Could be made a bit more sophisticated still.

Answer (score 1):

You just don't do that, a variable is a living thing, it's against its nature to store it like that, flat and dead in a string in the database.

If you want to replace some parts of a string with the content of a variable, use `sprintf()`.

Example

```
$stringFromTheDb = '<div>%s is not %s</div>';
```

Then use it with:

```
$finalString = sprintf($stringFromTheDb, 'this', 'that');

echo $finalString;
```

will result in:

```
<div>this is not that</div>
```

Comment: How could i forget about this? Well both answers (mine and this one) have use cases but in general I prefer this. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the variable inside the div is `$title`, you can `str_replace` it.

```
function test($string){
  $title = 'please print';
  echo str_replace('$title', $title, $string);
}
```

If you don't know the variables in the string, you can use a regex to get them (I used the regex from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)).

```
function test($string){
  $title = 'please print';
  $vars = '/(?<=\$)[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*/';
  preg_match_all($vars, $string, $replace);
  foreach($replace[0] as $r){
    $string = str_replace('$'.$r, $$r, $string);
  }
  echo $string;
}
```